# Rsizing The Spatial Dimensions Of a 5D Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

For training a deep learning based model, I have an input tensor with the size of [batch_size=32, channels=3, Temporal=16, H=128, w=192] that includes frames of a video. I need to resize the spatial size of the tensor to (H=224, w=224). In other words, I need to have a tensor with the size of [batch_size=32, channels=3, Temporal=16, H=224, w=224]. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`torch.nn.functional.interpolate`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.interpolate.html?highlight=interpolate#torch.nn.functional.interpolate):

```py
import torch.nn.functional as nnf

y = nnf.interpolate(x, size=(x.shape[2], 224, 224), mode='trilinear')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I  want to resize the spatial size (H,W) of a 4D tensor, how I should modify your solution?

Comment: @dtr43 please read the doc on `nnf.interpolate` it's all there.